# Nuxt: useFetch call gives wrong return type

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I guess the answer to this question might be very simple but I dont know how to do it.

I have the following code in my *pages/auth/login.vue*:

```
async login() {
    try {
        const { data } = await useFetch('/api/auth/login', {
            method: 'post',
            body: {
               username: this.username,
               password: this.password
            }
        });
        console.log(data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during login:', error);
        this.loginError = true;
    }
}
```

And my *server/api/auth/login.tsx*:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const { username, password } = await readBody(event)

    return {
        status: "200",
        message: "Lgon usccessful",
        user: username
     }
})
```

The call is working but the return type of the response is sth like:

[image]

How can I access the value which the call returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data return is a reactive data wrapped by ref, you could get access to the user like :

```js
   const { data } = await useFetch('/api/auth/login', {
            method: 'post',
            body: {
               username: this.username,
               password: this.password
            }
        });
        console.log(data.value.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

data is a `ref` so you should use `.value` to access its value.

```
data.value
```

read this page for more info:
https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch